# Comme, comme des ou comme de

Tags: prépositions, articles, adverbes, absence-d-article

Dans le paragraphe ci-dessous, je me demande s'il faut écrire *comme extensions*, *comme des extensions* ou bien *comme d'extensions* et pourquoi.

> La nouveauté de ce travail est la considération des caractéristiques poroélastiques du modèle. Récemment, un des auteurs s'est attaqué  au problème analogue dans le cas de la viscoélasticité.
>
> Ces deux schémas (poroélastique, viscoélastique) peuvent être considérés **comme extensions** / **comme d'extensions** / **comme des extensions** de l'approche originale, laquelle étudie seulement des matériaux acoustiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il est, nul doute, hors de question de dire ou écrire « comme d'extensions » ; c'est tout simplement incorrect. Les deux autres formes sont correctes.

Les sens sont différents.

> (TLFi) II. Morph. de compar. Dans ces emplois comme exprime une idée de similitude, l'écart avec l'idée d'identité pouvant être plus ou moins réduit selon le contexte.
>
> II C  5. Comme + subst. en appos.
> Nous avons longuement analysé cette suite [le Mariage à la mode]. Elle est, comme pensée et comme exécution, l'œuvre la plus parfaite de Hogarth.

Dans ce cas d'utilisation sans article « comme » signifie « en tant que », c'est à dire « sur le plan de sa nature qui est celle d'être quelque chose » (ici une pensée, une exécution).

Lorsque l'article est utilisé on comprend qu'il s'agit d'une similitude ou d'une comparaison ; deux cas se présentent. Il n'existe pas d'extension au préalable et « comme des extensions » signifie alors que la nature de la chose est celle de l'extension en général ; s'il existe déjà des extensions, alors il y a une légère ambiguïté et il peut s'agir de « une nouvelle extension » ou de « quelque chose dont la nature approche celle des extensions qui existent déjà »

Comment: [Définitivement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=d%C3%A9finitivement&T3&id=1102&id=1102)

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais personnellement utilisé « comme des extensions », mais « comme extensions » est également correct.

> La nouveauté de ce travail est la considération des caractéristiques poroélastiques du modèle. Récemment, un des auteurs s'est attaqué au problème analogue dans le cas de la viscoélasticité.
>
> Ces deux schémas (poroélastique, viscoélastique) peuvent être considérés **comme des extensions** de l'approche originale, laquelle étudie seulement des matériaux acoustiques.